# PlayerPrefs not working on android device but works in unity editor

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I know a lot of people has asked similar question but I am not able to get a solution for my problem. I created a email and  a password field and want it to save so that when a user opens the application his/her email and password reappears automatically. This whole process works fine in unity editor but not on my android device. Any help is appriciated. Below is the code I used.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerPref : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField emailI;
    public InputField passwordI;
    public InputField domainI;
    public Toggle rememberToggle;
    bool remeberIsOn;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        emailI.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("email","");
        passwordI.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("password","");
        domainI.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("domain","");
        

    }

    public void saveInput()
    {
        remeberIsOn = rememberToggle.isOn;
        if (remeberIsOn)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("email", emailI.text);
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("password", passwordI.text);
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("domain", domainI.text);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("email", "");
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("password", "");
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("domain", "");
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
        }
```

Comment: How is `saveInput` called? Are you sure it is?

Comment: Also, do you confirm that `rememberToggle.isOn` actually returns `true`?

Comment: Using your device check the logcat output messages to see what's happening. Also you can check if the data in a file on the device is properly saved. The file destination should be as follows /data/data/pkg-name/shared_prefs/pkg-name.xml

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not calling saveInput